# How to define function that doesn't take any arguments

Tags: expl3

Usuall, I am using `\cs_new:Nn \module_function_name:n { Function got parameter: #1 }`. However, now I find myself in a situation where I would like to define a function that does not take any argument at all. This function is supposed to encapsulate a piece of functionality that does perform some checks using some ifs and if these checks fails, the function emits an error. Thus, no inputs needed.

However, it seems that there currently is no support for defining functions that don't take any arguments as this gives me an error:

```
\cs_new:Nn \module_my_func {
   Function without parameter
}
```

More specifically, the error is

```
LaTeX3 Error: Function '\module_my_func' contains no ':'.
```

Thus, my question is: How do define a function that takes no parameter?

Comment: Function names have `__` in case they are private, then the module name, followed by the proper name; finally a colon that precedes the argument specification. This is not enforced if you use `\cs_new(_protected):Npn`, which is a reason why I prefer `\cs_new(_protected):Nn`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that having empty parameter specifications in function names is permissible and indeed the correct way to declare functions taking no arguments. Therefore, simply adding a ':' to the end of my function's name solved the issue:

```
\cs_new:Nn \module_my_func: {
   Function without parameter
}
```

Comment: Indeed: standard 'function' names at the `expl3` level _must_ contain a `:`